# How to create Net.TCP WCF binding for\using SOAP 1.1?

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, net.tcp

How to create Net.TCP WCF binding for\using SOAP 1.1? Is it posible?

**If yes.**
 What do I need?

- MSDN if there is any help on this.
- Open Source Libs/wrappers.
- Tutorials and blog articles on How to do it.

---

**If no**: I need know where did you get the information from (link to MSDN or other official WCF information resource).

Comment: You are asking how to create WCF service?

Comment: I don't see how you can do that; you can create a "custombinding" but you can only set the "messageVersion" to "Soap11" on a "TextEncoding" element, and that kinda defeats the whole point of using netTcp (which uses much more efficient binary encoding).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- SOAP is an XML format.
- Net tcpbinding is a binary format.

They are two different things.

What you can do is to expose a service with 2 endpoints, one SOAP and one binary.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you need a SOAP/TCP protocol (SOAP-based or XML Infoset-based) and you want to keep your solution open for interoperability like WCF - WSIT (Java) you need to use a tool like WCF-Xtensions from Noemax.

http://www.noemax.com/global/press_releases/september_24_2007.html

Oracle has a SOAP/TCP recommendation, but I don’t really see a lot of out of the box components, etc which implement it. It is a shame because it is pretty fast and works on both Java and .NET

http://java.sun.com/webservices/reference/apis-docs/soap-tcp-v1.0.pdf

I am not aware of free components. If you know any please comment on my post. I am working on a WCF - WSIT (Metro) integration project and WS-Http turned out to be very slow.

Answer (score 0):

I think TCP binding also uses SOAP protocol, but within SOAP message it uses binary encoding instead of text. For more clarification please see this article:

- http://forums.asp.net/t/1864812.aspx/1

MSDN:

- [Chapter 7: Message and Transport Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648863.aspx)